# Hide icon when form field is disabled

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form in which i have a datepicker that has an icon that shows the calendar when is clicked on the input field.

I have a case where my field is disabled, the calendar is not showing when the form field OR the icon is clicked, but I also want to hide the icon when the div has the "disabled" attribute.

HTML:

```
<div class="control-group no-clear" ydatepicker ng-model="data.date"
                 ng-disabled="(data.id && data.isRecurrent()) || saving">
                <label for="date">Date</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="date" ng-model="data.date" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="picker" ui-date="Config.dateOptions" ui-date-format="DD, MM d yy" ng-model="data.date"></div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.control-group.date {
  height: 44px;

 .controls {
    position: relative;

  input {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  i {
    color: $color20;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    @include transform(rotate(180deg));
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 1px;
    pointer-events: none !important;

    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
  }

  .icon-x {
    color: $color30;
    pointer-events: inherit !important;
  }
}
```

[What I have now](https://jsfiddle.net/c7t5qha0/2/)

Also, for more info, when inspecting the element in the browser, the "control-group" gets the "date" class and also disabled="disabled". Under the controls div, i also have the disabled tag on the input field, and an i element that contains the icon that i am talking about.

I have tried

```
.control-group.date:disabled .controls i {
   display:none;
}
```

but it isn't working. Also, if I change the display attribute from my CSS from inline-block to none, the icon isn t displayed even if the field is disabled even if not.

I m expecting that my icon to be not displayed when the field is disabled.

Comment: `:disabled` does _not_ select elements with the _class_ `disabled`

Comment: (And setting the `disabled` _attribute_ in HTML on a `div` element doesn’t make much sense.)

Comment: The div hasn t the "disabled" class, but has the "disabled='disabled'" tag.

Comment: Which as I said is nonsense to begin with - you can not “disable” a div element. Plus, could you please pay a little bit more attention to keeping your problem description consistent then, because initially you said, _“but I also want to hide the icon when the form has the 'disabled' class”_.

Comment: My bad, you're right. Just edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
.control-group.date[disabled="disabled"] .controls i {
   display:none;
}
```